# SQL query to group results into hourly buckets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple MySQL table

```
Name  |  Time  |  Count
James |  11:00 |  10
Simon |  11:00 |  5
James |  11:30 |  4
Oliver|  11:30 |  2
James |  12:00 |  1
etc.
```

I would like to create a MySQL query which sums the Count for each person and outputs a last 1 hour value, a last 3 hour value, a last 6 hour value, a last 12 hour value and a last 24 hour value.

e.g. if the time is now 12:59 the above table would output:

```
Name  |  Last-1  |  Last-3  | Last-6
James |  1       |  15      | 15
Simon |  0       |  5       | 5
Oliver|  0       |  2       | 2
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query? So far I have:

```
SELECT name, HOUR( NOW( ) ) - HOUR( time ) AS lasthours, SUM( count ) AS c
FROM table
GROUP BY name, lasthours
HAVING lasthours =0
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Which gives me the past hour, but how do I get the additional columns?

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The accepted answer needed tweaking slightly and came out as follows:

```
SELECT  name , 
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=0,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last hour` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=3,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 3 hours` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=6,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 6 hours` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=12,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 12 hours` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=24,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 24 hours` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=48,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 2 days` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=72,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 3 days` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=96,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 4 days` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=120,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 5 days` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=144,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last 6 days` ,
        SUM( IF( HOUR( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  time ) ) <=168,  count , 0 ) ) AS  `Last week`
FROM  table
GROUP BY  name
ORDER BY `Last hour` DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   `name`,
         SUM(IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), `Time`)) <= 1, `Count`, 0)) AS `Last-1`,
         SUM(IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), `Time`)) <= 3, `Count`, 0)) AS `Last-3`,
         SUM(IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), `Time`)) <= 6, `Count`, 0)) AS `Last-6`
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY `name`
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/809d3/1/0).

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Though I had to change CURTIME() to NOW()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Select Name,Sum(Case When Hour(Now)-Hour(Time) <= 1 Then Count Else 0 End) As Last1,
Sum(Case When Hour(Now)-Hour(Time) Between 2 AND 3 Then Count Else 0 End) As Last3,
Sum(Case When Hour(Now)-Hour(Time) Between 4 And 6 Then Count Else 0 End) As Last6
From name
Order By
```

Comment: With a bit of tweaking this works, but I prefer the solution below. Thank you anyway!